# What's the purpose of VK_PRINT?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keycode

While processing keys I assumed that the virtual key `VK_PRINT` (0x2A) is the print key on my keyboard. But this assumption was false. I need to work with `VK_SNAPSHOT` (0x2C) which is `VK_PRINT+2`. But what is `VK_PRINT` for? Looking at MSDN I got the feeling we should all forget about this keycode...

What's up with `VK_PRINT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `VK_PRINT` keycode is from back in the days of the 83/84 key keyboard (think IBM XT and the IBM AT machines).  The 'Print' key on this keyboards was shared with the numeric keypad's '*' key (instead of the `PrtSc`/`SysRq` key as is usual today).

See http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm for some details on the history of IBM PC compatible keyboards.

Comment: So it was basically a different key which doesn't exist anymore today?

Comment: @Heinrich: I think that's right, but I'm not 100% certain. I don't have ready access to the source for the Windows keyboard driver (it might  be in the WDK, but I'm not sure), and my notes about keyboard scancodes from my days doing keyboard drivers are pretty much long gone.

Comment: It sounds reasonable and would also explain its scarce representation in the MSDN. Because nobody needs it anymore.